# Getting error on mongoose connect

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm totally new in nodejs and mongodb .
I'm getting this error after run `nodemon server.js` .

```
  ../build/release/bson' code 'module_not_found code:MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
```

here is my code :

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://root:123456@ds045998.mongolab.com:45998/mean');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'conncetion error ...'));
db.once('open', function callback(){
    console.log('mean database is opend');
});
```

i think this is not error because i get this also : "`mean database is opend`"

and i'm using mongolab for conncetion .

```
var express = require('express'),
    stylus = require('stylus'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    session = require('express-session'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    bson = require('bson');
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `sudo npm install`

Comment: and make sure your `package.json` is contains all the required packages.

Comment: no i did this and checked package.json but still getting this error